# Erlang epmd issues - RabbitMQ and Ejabberd on same host

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, ejabberd, epmd

I used to run two ejabberd servers along with RabbitMQ server on one box. However, something crashed and epmd shows what is following:

`$ ./epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name ejabberdjabberpl at port 48654
name ejabberd at port 55243
name rabbit_crypto at port 25673
name rabbit at port 38794`

However, only *ejabberdjabberpl* running - other are dead and they are not listening on the ports. Now, when I am trying to start crased RabbitMQ server or other ejabberd server - they both says that **ejabberd** or **rabbit** or **rabbit_crypto** already exist on the node.

I tried to remove the with -stop but it does not work:

`$ ./epmd -stop rabbit
epmd: local epmd responded with <>`

Answer (score 1):

How did you know that there is no rabbit and ejabberd anymore?
Typical problem with erlang-based applications is that it's scripts used something called 'cookie' to communicate with services. And if someone accidentally deletes this secret cookie, scripts stop working.

Try to ensure that rabbit and ejabberd stopped by inspecting `ps aux | grep beam`

Comment: I have checked (using netstat) if there are application listening on these ports. All beams have been removed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that no Erlang cluster code is actually running, when that happen, you should actually kill / restart epmd. It sometimes get stuck with old data, preventing you to restart your service.

Comment: I don't want to kill other nodes which are running on same epmd.